# findByName isn't work [Spring boot]

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have a problem with Spring boot.
I created Entity and Repository, but method findByName in Repository isn't work.
My url:

http://localhost:8080/student/search/findByName?name=Artem
In Google chrome: localhost not found, but search is mapped.

Entity:

```
@Getter @Setter
@Entity @Table(name = "Student")

public class Student extends BaseEntity{
    private String name;
    private String dateOfBirthDay;
    private String sex;
    private String phoneNumber;
}
```

BaseEntity:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@MappedSuperclass
public class BaseEntity {
    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE) @Column protected Long id;
```

My Repository:

```
@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "student", path = "student")
public interface StudentRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Student, Long> {
    Student findByName(@Param("name") String name);
}
```

Application:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableTransactionManagement

public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

Application.yaml:

```
spring:
    application:
        name: students
    datasource:
        driverClassName: org.postgresql.Driver
        url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/students
        username: postgres
        password: postgres
    jpa:
      hibernate:
        ddl-auto: update
server:
    port: 8080
```

Comment: @javaguy Read about RepositoryRestResource, it's work like controller.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to create a resource class, works like controller. Here a simple example:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/yourPath") //students, whatever
public class StudentsResource {

@Autowired
private StudentRepository studentRepository;

//type media that you want to show (json, xml...in this case is JSON)
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = { MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE })

// <Student> is the entity, object
@RequestMapping(value = "/yourPath/{studentName}")
public ResponseEntity<Student> findByName(@pathVariable("studentName") String name) {
    Student student = studentRepository.findByName(name);

    if(student == null){
     //handler your own exception here
    }

    //show the student as json object
    return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).body(student);
}
```

**Note:** that's the resource class. But your problem is about localhost, so if you are using Spring Boot, see if your "application.properties" is correct. Here my example:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/yourDataBase
spring.datasource.username=yourUser
spring.datasource.password=yourPassword

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update //makes the spring create the database automatic!
```